# Unable to pip2.7 install at Mac

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install 'mrjob' package at Python 2.7. However when I ran 'pip2.7 install mrjob', the following error appears. Does anyone have the solution to this? Note: I have both Python 2.7 and 3.5 install at my mac.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto'
```

Comment: Do you installation as root? Directory "site-packages" for Python 2.7 is writable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with elevated privileges.

**sudo** pip2.7 install mrjob

Comment: Hey Limbo, I tried running your command and it still does not work. This is what happens    `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-tU5xq5-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'`

Comment: I ran the following code and it works: `sudo pip2.7 install --ignore-installed mrjob`